# Loading more results from database using $_POST (or $_GET?)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a blog page "plugin" in my own little cms and it's displayed with return() on the index.php.

Part of the index.php:

```
$id = (isset($_GET['m_id'])) ? $_GET['m_id'] : 1; //menu id
$sql = "SELECT m_cim, m_tartalom, m_plugin
        FROM menu
        WHERE m_s_id = (SELECT s_id FROM statusz WHERE s_nev='aktiv')
        AND m_id = ".$id;
$eredmeny = mysql_query($sql);

if (@mysql_num_rows($eredmeny) == 0) {
    $tartalom = "<h1>404!</h1>\n";
}
else {
    $sor = mysql_fetch_assoc($eredmeny);
    $tartalom = "<h2>{$sor['m_cim']}</h2>
    <span class=\"tart\">{$sor['m_tartalom']}</span>\n";
    if(!empty($sor['m_plugin'])){
        $tartalom.=include("./modul/{$sor['m_plugin']}");
    }
}

<section id="content">
    <?php print $tartalom; ?>
</section>
```

The posts come from a database and the news.php is included in the index.php.
This is the "plugin" news.php

```
$aktiv="(SELECT s_id FROM statusz WHERE s_nev='aktiv')";
$sql = "SELECT hir_id, hir_cim, hir_tartalom, hir_ido
        FROM hirek
        WHERE hir_s_id=".$aktiv."
        ORDER BY hir_id DESC";
$eredmeny = mysql_query($sql);

$kimenet = "";
while ($sor = mysql_fetch_assoc($eredmeny)) {
    $kimenet.= "<article class=\"hirek\">
    <h3><a href=\"blog.php?hir_id={$sor['hir_id']}\">{$sor['hir_cim']}</a></h3>
    <span class=\"hido\">{$sor['hir_ido']}</span>
    <p class=\"htart\">".substr(strip_tags($sor['hir_tartalom']),0,200)."</p>
    <a href=\"blog.php?hir_id={$sor['hir_id']}\">Tovább...</a>
</article>\n";
}
return $kimenet;
```

If I use a php pagination, I only saw, that the page number is posted via the ‘GET’ method, but in that case, I use the GET method for the menu id, and when I want to post something else with get, the result will be the menu item with the actual id. Is it possible to use $_GET method for this?
I think [this technique](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/loading-more-results-from-database)  can solve my problem, but I don't know if it's outdated/not-so-good/do-not-use-it or not.
When I find somewhere a solution for my actual problem, somebody always says that "do not use it, because..." "it's not the best idea, because..." "this is not the best solution,because.."
Can I trust in this?

Comment: The only problem with using a value from `$_GET` or `$_POST` in a query is if you just stick it in the query without sanitizing it then a user can do an SQL injection attack on you.  That's why you should use prepared statements.

Comment: and to be able to use prepared statements in the first place, you'll have to switch from using the mysql extension (which is officially deprecated anyway) to either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo)

Comment: Thank you. This is my first year at school and we only learned the mysql. I've heard about PDO, but i don't understand every part of it yet. I don't know how to switch fast and i have only 4 days to change my code and if something goes wrong and my code won't work, i'll get a bad grade.